# How can I escape forward/backslashes and spaces in R

Tags: r, data-science

I like to use R to analyse data but I don't know how to escape these things in R. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance. [image: How can I handle with these columns?]

Comment: Escaping  names is usually done with backticks: `data_frame$\`Pts/G\``

Comment: Thanks! It was quite easy. Shame on me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to use the `clean_names()` function from the `janitor` package.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

my_df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    `xGD/90` `Pts/G`
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     2.10    4.38
#>  2     4.93    5.35
#>  3     3.13    2.99
#>  4     4.66    4.50
#>  5     3.05    4.26
#>  6     4.32    5.26
#>  7     3.44    3.87
#>  8     5.44    3.96
#>  9     5.06    4.28
#> 10     4.37    4.67
```

```r
my_df %>% 
    clean_names()
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    x_gd_90 pts_g
#>      <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1    2.10  4.38
#>  2    4.93  5.35
#>  3    3.13  2.99
#>  4    4.66  4.50
#>  5    3.05  4.26
#>  6    4.32  5.26
#>  7    3.44  3.87
#>  8    5.44  3.96
#>  9    5.06  4.28
#> 10    4.37  4.67
```

Then you can can use whatever function

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>